# Нагрузка в Linux

Tags: linux

Всем привет. Я уже задал этот вопрос на РутКод, но, как мне кажется, он имеет право быть задан и здесь, так как относится к ядру Linux

**Команда:** sa -m

**Вывод:** bsdmacs 14415 291.20re 28.33cp 0avio 561469k

Первые четыре значения прозрачны и ясны, но что значит 561469k и каким образом считается?

Где я искал информацию:

1. глава Timing Measurements книги
       Understanding the Linux kernel.
2. man sa, естественно.

Буду рад любым ключевым словам для поиска.

Comment: @avp, Вы давали верный ответ. К сожалению, он был оформлен в виде комментария. Оформите, пожалуйста его в виде ответа и я его приму.

Comment: @avp, разбираю исходники - появились сомнения в правильности Вашего ответа. Но, в любом, случае как идея он имеет место быть.

Comment: @bsdmacs, Вы правы, это была именно идея (основана на интуитивном представлении о работе планировщика).

Куда делось Ваше обсуждение с @mikillskegg (где я оставил комментарий) ума не приложу.

-

Насколько помню (man уже закрыл) идея была в том, что 561469k это количество "квантов диспетчирования" в расчете на одно ядро, запланированное всем процессам данного пользователя. 

-

IMHO поскольку не все выданные "кванты" отрабатываются полностью (из-за ввода/вывода) сравнение их с 28.33cp (минуты CPU) затруднительно.

---

**Просьба !  Разберетесь (с исходниками) опубликуйте результат.**

Comment: Постараюсь разобраться в течение месяца и выложить результат - сейчас очень много работы.

Answer (score 1):

Еу в что здесь странного - это так называемый "тик", который довольно часто используется как единица измерения кванта. Берет свое происхождение, как ни странно от частоты сети переменного тока. Так и определяется в исходных текстах ядра как HZ

Comment: @voldemarus, в данном случае HZ - это частота генерации прерываний системным таймером. Никакого отношения к частоте сети переменного тока не имеет.

Comment: Это был не ответ, а комментарий, почему тик равен именно 50 Гц. После того, как авторы ответа самоустранились (?) , комментарий почему то превратился в ответ :-(